# Creating Table How to key in more than one primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is how to make this work basically an office and non office workers can have more than one loan but since our loan id primary key I can't more than one any ideas how to do this?

```
  CREATE TABLE loaner 
  (
      l_id NUMBER(10) primary key,
      type VARCHAR2(20),
      no_days_overdue NUMBER(3),
      loan_start_date date,
      loan_end_date date,
      fine_imposed NUMBER(55),
      constraint loaner_uk unique (l_id, type),
      constraint chk_type check (type='office' or type='nonoffice')
    );

    commit;

CREATE TABLE office 
(
  office_id NUMBER(5) primary key,
  l_id NUMBER(10) ,
  type VARCHAR2(10),
  office_forname VARCHAR2(30),
  office_surname VARCHAR2(30),
  email VARCHAR2(50),
  address VARCHAR2 (100),
  constraint office_fk foreign key (l_id, type) references loaner (l_id, type),
  constraint office_type_chk check (type='OFFICE')
);
commit;

CREATE TABLE nonoffice 
(
  nonoffice_id NUMBER(5), 
  l_id NUMBER(5),
  type VARCHAR2(10),
  non_forname VARCHAR2(30),
  non_surname VARCHAR2(30),
  constraint nonoffice_loaner_fk foreign key (l_id, type) references loaner (l_id, type),
  constraint nonoffice_type_chk check (brw_type='nonoffice')
);
commit;
```

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow but from what it sounds like, you want a nonoffice and an office to have more then one loan?  If this is the case, add PK of office to loaner as a FK and add the PK of nonoffice to loaner as a FK instead of adding loaner PK to office and nonoffice as FK

Comment: @Stc5097 then there will a problem if loaner will have no pk...

Comment: loaner will still have a PK.  You want a one to many relationship from office to loaner and from nonoffice to loaner.  With this relationship, the PK of the ONE side must be present as a FK in the many side.  You just have it reversed

Comment: so basically you mean like this? (sorry for making it more complicated i just want to understand and learn)
1. keep the loaner id as a pk in loaner table
2. put the loaner id into both office and non office table? @Stc5097

Comment: below is how I would create this DB schema

Answer (score 0):

```
        CREATE TABLE loaner 
          (
              l_id NUMBER(10) primary key,
              type VARCHAR2(20),
              no_days_overdue NUMBER(3),
              loan_start_date date,
              loan_end_date date,
              fine_imposed NUMBER(55),
              office_id NUMBER(5),
              nonoffice_id NUMBER(5),
              constraint office_fk foreign key (office_id) references office(office_id),
              constraint nonoffice_fk foreign key (nonoffice_id) references nonoffice(nonoffice_id)
            );

            commit;

        CREATE TABLE office 
        (
          office_id NUMBER(5) primary key,
          l_id NUMBER(10) ,
          type VARCHAR2(10),
          office_forname VARCHAR2(30),
          office_surname VARCHAR2(30),
          email VARCHAR2(50),
          address VARCHAR2 (100),
        );
        commit;

        CREATE TABLE nonoffice 
        (
          nonoffice_id NUMBER(5) primary key, 
          l_id NUMBER(5),
          type VARCHAR2(10),
          non_forname VARCHAR2(30),
          non_surname VARCHAR2(30),
        );
        commit;
```